# Query excel based database from SQLDeveloper

Tags: excel, odbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, jdbc-odbc

I am on a Windows 7 machine and have configured a ODBC connection by name of 'MyExcelDb' to an excel file. I am able to programatically connect to 'MyExcelDb' using type-1 jdbc driver and everything is working fine.

I now want to use Oracle SQLDveloper to query the DSN 'MyExcelDb' but I am not able to make this connection as I do not find any option for ODBC Connection. I have tried using the 'advanced' option in Oracle section and tried putting custom jdbc URL as 'jdbc:odbc:excelDB' bugt to no avail.

I have tried adding entries in SQLDeveloper for third party drivers like: 

 - sourceforge.net/projects/xlsql/ 

  - code.google.com/p/sqlsheet/ 

  - hxtt.com/excel.html

Despite this but no new connection option would appear and I am still struggling to make connection between the two.

I have searched around and found that I could install Oracle and add a TNS for the excel and that way I may be able to connect using the Oracle TNS in SQLDeveloper. Installing Oracle database but would be like killing a mosquito using a canon.

I wonder if there is a simple solution to my problem.

Comment: Why would you like to use SQL Developer to "query" an excel worksheet/book? Is there a function or any kind of processing that cannot be accomplished via Excel commands?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following [Oracle's guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/owb.112/e10582/loading_ms_data.htm#WBDOD10661) for connecting to Excel files? Did you set up a system DSN as described in step three of the Oracle guide. Importing files into the database is routine and simple but using SQL Developer in the manner you describe, without the client installed. [Here is an example of reading an Excel file via PL/SQL](https://technology.amis.nl/2013/01/19/read-a-excel-xlsx-with-plsql/).

My question is why use SQL Developer to manipulate a datastore in Excel when Excel is designed to manipulate the data?

Comment: Hi Nathan, 
1) Yes I have configured a DSN by name of 'MyExcelDb'. I have mentioned it in my question.
2) The two questions seem different. In my case excel is the database and is to be queried from SQLDeveloper. I don’t have Oracle database server or client installed. In other question referred by you Oracle is the database and this Oracle database is to be queried from within excel.

Comment: I have updated the answer since your two questions are different.